# How to convert "923007501" to a hh:mm:ss format?

Tags: c#

I'm currently trying to convert a subtitle-file from one format to another, but I'm struggling at bit with the timecode-fomat used in the original subtitle-file. For example, "923007501" is supposed to be roughly 00:01:30 (hh:mm:ss) but I don't really know how to convert that number to a hh:mm:ss format.

For some subtitle-files I can simply use something like `TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(timecode);`, but that doesn't seem work for the previous example.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
        DateTime dt = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0).AddSeconds(923007501).ToLocalTime();
        String.Format("{0:HH:mm:ss}", dt); // here is your formatted datetime
```

Comment: `AddSeconds(ts)` this won't work. You should add `double`, not `TimeSpan`

Comment: sorry yeah u are right u have just to use directly your timecode in AddSeconds Method `DateTime dt = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0).AddSeconds(timecode).ToLocalTime();` , if it helps u please set the answer correct :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but that's not what I was looking for. Your code converts "923007501" to a point in time in a 24h circle (like 9 o'clock for example), right? But I'm looking for a timestamp in a movie (that starts at 00:00:00 and ends at 02:10:20 or whatever the duration of the movie is)